# Custom Composite widget in *.ui.xml

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I would like to create a custom GWT composite widget that I can later use this way in *.ui.xml using uiBinder (cw is prefix for my custom widgets package):

```
<cw:CustomPanel>  
  <cw:header><g:Label>test</g:Label></cw:header>  
  <cw:content><g:Label>test</g:Label></cw:content>  
</cw:CustomPanel>
```

In short, I would expect that `setHeader` and `setContent` methods on my custom widget are called by the framework somehow.

Is that at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `@UiChild` is for, see the JavaDoc at http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/uibinder/client/UiChild.html

If you want to keep the method names `setHeader` and `setContent` (instead of `addHeader` and `addContent`), you'll have to use

```java
@UiChild(tagname = "header")
void setHeader(Widget headerWidget) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `setHeader(String title)` and `setContent(String content)` methods in your widget's Java class. In these methods add text to your header and content panel respectively. Then you can use this widget in Ui:Binder this way:

```
<cw:CustomPanel header="test" content=test" />
```